# using map's initializer list inside constructor initializer

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, pointer-to-member

Trying to create a map of int to member function pointer and initialize it inside a constructor initializer.
Like this:

```
class X
{
    using STATEFUNC = void(X::*)(int);
public:
    X() : m{ { 1, &setState1 } } {}

    void setState1(int x) { cout << "state1" << endl; }

    void setState2(int x) { cout << "state2" << endl; }


    std::map<int, STATEFUNC> m;
};
```

I would say this is correct, but Visual studio 2017 says:

> Error C2664   'std::map,std::allocator>>::map(std::initializer_list>)':
>   cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer list' to
>   'std::initializer_list>'
>
> Error C2276   '&': illegal operation on bound member function
>   expression

When you remove the address of operator from the member function the first error message stays the same but the second changes to:

> Error C3867   'X::setState1': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a
>   pointer to member

How do you initialize a map of int to member function pointer inside a constructor initializer list?

Comment: Interesting.  Not sure why but it requires the class name here.  Hopefully someone will know why `X() : m{ { 1, &X::setState1 } } {}` works but `X() : m{ { 1, &setState1 } } {}` doesn't

Comment: `identifier` can never be used to take the address of a member function (either explicitly with `&` or by decay); you always have to use a qualified-id

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with

```
X() : m{ { 1, &X::setState1 } } {}
```

Using only `&setState1` I get, from g++, the following message error

> error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&X::setState1’ [-fpermissive]

From clang++ the error is simply

> error: must explicitly qualify name of member function when taking its address

**-- EDIT --**

My answer explain how to solve the problem.

To understand why `&X::setState1` works and `&setState1` doesn't, please see the StoryTeller's answer (+1)

Answer (score 14):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45816776/using-maps-initializer-list-inside-constructor-initializer/45816908#45816908) by [max66](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6022656/max66) is the fix. As for why it's the fix: the reason is that your code does not create a pointer to a member. To quote n4659 (last C++17 draft, but previous standard revisions say the same):

[[expr.unary.op/4]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.unary#op-4)

> **A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit & is used and its
>   operand is a qualified-id not enclosed in parentheses.** [ Note: That
>   is, the expression &(qualified-id), where the qualified-id is enclosed
>   in parentheses, does not form an expression of type “pointer to
>   member”. Neither does qualified-id, because there is no implicit
>   conversion from a qualified-id for a non-static member function to the
>   type “pointer to member function” as there is from an lvalue of
>   function type to the type “pointer to function” ([conv.func]). **Nor is
>   &unqualified-id a pointer to member, even within the scope of the
>   unqualified-id's class.**  — end note ]

`X::setState1` is a qualified id, but `setState1` is not.

Comment: There's a good reason for this distinction, I think. E.g. one would expect ``&m`` to be of type ``std::map<int, STATEFUNC> *``, so a different syntax is needed, specifically ``&X::m`` to get a ``std::map<int, STATEFUNC> X::*``. It is then consistent to require the latter syntax also for non-static methods, even if the syntax with unqualified-id is illegal.

Comment: @ArneVogel - You are very much correct. Furthermore, one need not even make a distinction between member functions and data members when defining pointers to members. If we have `T C::* pm = &C::m;`, then the declaration is correct whether `T` is an object type (which m matches) or a function alias like `using T = void(void);` (and m is a member function with this prototype). The syntax is *very consistent* this way, despite the verbosity.